# Searching for sequence of operators in space of infinite dimension

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I want to find an infinite dimensional space $X$ and a sequence of operators $T_n: X \to X$ of finite rank such that $T_n$ converge pointwase to $Id$.

I was thinking about $\ell^2$ but it is difficult to find this suquence with finite rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots)\in\ell^2$ then define $T_nx = (x_1,\dots,x_n,0,0,\dots)$. These operators obviously bounded, linear, and have finite rank for each $n$. They also converge pointwise to the identity as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: How to prove that Tn converge pointwise to identity? using the definition is difficult

Comment: You have to show that $T_nx\to x$ as $n\to\infty$. $\|x-T_n\|_{\ell^2}^2=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}x_i^2$, which goes to 0 as $n\to\infty$ since $\|x\|_{\ell^2}<\infty$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}T_nx=x$ for all $x\in\ell^2$